# Integration of Gaussian random variables.

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose $g(t)$ is Gaussian random variable for real $t \in D $. Assume $[t,t+\Delta t] \subseteq D $.

I want to prove that, for
\begin{equation}
\xi = \int_t ^{t+\Delta t} g (\tau ) d\tau
\end{equation}
$\xi$ is Gaussian random variable.

I already know that for random variables $X_1, X_2$ with normal distribution,
\begin{equation}
X = X_1 + X_2 
\end{equation}
is have normal distribution.
However, I have difficulty on continuous and integral instead of discontinuous and sum.

Does anyone have idea or counter examples of my question?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general that the sum of Gaussian random variables is Gaussian - this is only true if they are independent, as well. In a similar way, your claim about the integral is not true without some further assumptions on the covariance structure of your Gaussian process $g(t)$.

A well-known counterexample goes as follows. Let $X,Y$ be independent standard Gaussians, and let
$$
Z=\text{sign}(X)\cdot |Y|.
$$
Then $Z$ is also standard Gausian, but it can be shown that $X+Z$ is not Gaussian at all.

Comment: Then, is there any theorem about integrals of independent Gaussian variables? I want to know what assumption is needed if there is relative theorem about that.

Comment: It is not even clear what this would mean exactly, since a Gaussian process with independent values is not continuous - rather it is a type of white noise, which is not even defined as a function (it is too rough)! Perhaps you can get a better response by asking a question that is more specific to the specific process $g(t)$ you have in mind.

Comment: I was studying physics about Langevin Equation. Since $g(t)$ is a type of noise, I think it does not hold rigorously. Thanks.

Comment: A rigorous statement and proof can be constructed using basic Ito calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus. However if you are after something a little simpler, consider a theorem that applies to Riemann approximations of the integral (rather than the integral itself), in which case there are no such difficulties.